# Access LSB of a byte and replace it with a value(1 or 0)

Tags: c#

Here is the scenario, I have a list of numbers both positive and negatives. And another list of bits(0's and 1's). I have to replace these bits to the LSB's of every number in the 1st list (i.e:- of numbers).

```
for (int k = 0; k< 8; k++)
{
    i1 = index[k, 0];
    i2 = index[k, 1];
    string str1 = Convert.ToString(d[i1,i2], 2);
    str1 = str1.Substring(Math.Max(str1.Length - 8, 0)).PadLeft(8, '0');
    str1[0] = Tnbinary[k];
}
```

It won't allow me to modify str[0] - it says that it is only readable. What am I doing wrong and how can I modify my number?

Comment: Why on earth are using strings for number operations??? It should be a simple bitwise operation.

Comment: Are you actually trying to get the form as a string, or change the value in the byte?

Comment: cannot be assigned to, it is readonly

Comment: @Jon Skeet I just want to replace LSB with my desired bit value.

Answer (score 3):

You could use bit operations:

```
byte b = -3;
byte b0 = (byte)(b & 254);   // Make LSB 0
byte b1 = (byte)(b | 1);     // Make LSB 1
```

If you're using signed bytes, just replace `byte` with `sbyte`.

Comment: I have both positve and negative numbers coming randomly from an array

Comment: @Ehsan: Byte in C# is unsigned - there's no such thing as a negative byte.

Comment: @Jon Skeet ok. I tell you the scenario ,  I have a list of numbers both positive and negatives. And another list of bits(0's and 1's) .I have to replace these bits to the LSB's of every number in the 1st list(i.e:- of numbers)

Answer (score 1):

If this is really a byte, why you don't do bit arithmetic, something like this:

```
new_byte = (old_byte & ~1) | new_bit
```